# How can i hide the calendar-div inside the jQuery-ui datepicker by JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, hide, uidatepicker

JQuery-ui will generate a div with a "calendar-div" class. Sadly this div is no child element from my origin div. So if i have multiple Divs, i can't get the calendar-div which belongs to the origin datepicker-field.

I would like to hide this div by JavaScript code. Are there posibilities to get the objects of de generated divs?

Comment: Will your origin divs generate only one calender-div?

Comment: And exactly how the calender div will be generated? By `onclick` or something like that?

Comment: it will be generated by the standard jQuery-UI datepicker function.

Comment: add some code to your question

Comment: @bitrevolution, add some code to your question². How your datepicker works? You click on the text field and the calendar shows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly do you mean by `calender-div`. If it is the div shown when date picker origin is clicked, you may get it like this:

```
$(origin-selector).datepicker("widget")
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution i searched!